# How do I add a new directory via DNN skin installation?

Tags: dotnetnuke, manifest

How do you add a new directory to DNN upon skin install? Is through the  reference in the manifest?

Comment: Are you adding a directory to hold images and such?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can create a new directory through a manifest file.  This applies to modules, skins - anything that uses a manifest file.

You will need to use the fileComponent in the manifest file, and specifically, the basePath element in order to specify where in the website your files will be installed.  You can also install in relative paths.

See more here : http://www.dotnetnuke.com/Resources/Wiki/Page/Manifest-File-Component.aspx